# Select records from ResultSet java

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I have a long query in Java which is put in a result set and executed by the executeQuery(string) method. Now I need to traverse this result set, query each of the records in the result set (method get_linked_OrgTickets contains this query) and output only those rows which return something in Vector linkedToTicket from the ResultSet. Can I sort of traverse this ResultSet and copy the said rows into another result set or maybe remove the rows not to be outputted from the ResultSet? Is there another way to solve this?

```
if (linked == J.LINKED_TO_ORG){
    while (rs.next()){
           Vector linkedToTicket = Ticket.get_linked_OrgTickets(con, rs.getInt(Ticket.FLD_ID)); 

           if (linkedToTicket != null)
           {                                
          // if there are linked tickets in the result set, output them only

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: ** These subqueries can't be integrated with the main query. The only way to do that is to execute the main query once without this and the second time with it included which would be too inefficient. ResultSet class does not seem to contain methods for deleting a row without affecting the database or for building a ResultSet 'manually'.

Please help!

Comment: So, where is this snippet failing? What have you tried?

Comment: it will depend on the logic of `get_linked_OrgTickets` and your query. You "filter" could be part of the first query.

Comment: It can't be part of the first query since I need to get the id's of the tickets returned by a number of criteria and check if these id's are linked to other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could manipulate the cursor in the resulset and pickup the right data. Something like this

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(
            " SELECT col1 FROM tablename");
rs.absolute(5); // moves the cursor to the fifth row of rs
String field = rs.getString("MY_FIELD");
```

however, be careful not to call `updaterow` because you will modify the underlying data row

Comment: Thanks @fgo for your answer :) have you any idea if I can then insert these rows in another result set manually?